# response.json is not a function. AngularFire

Tags: json, angular, observable, angularfire2

So I'm building an app using AngularFire2, This is in a service but when the function search gets ran it calls the error response.json is not a function. Firebase returns an observable and I'm not sure why this snippet wouldn't work.

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Article } from '../models/index';

  search(term: string): Observable<Article[]> {
    return this.af.database
      .list('/articles/', {
        query: {
          orderByChild: "title",
          equalTo: term,
          limitToFirst: 10
        }
      })
      .map(response => response.json().data as Article[]);
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AngularFire2's `list` observable does not emit a HTTP response object. It emits an array of anonymous objects that represent the items that match the query.

If `Article` is an interface, you can remove the `map` operator and cast the observable itself:

```ts
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Article } from '../models/index';

search(term: string): Observable<Article[]> {
  return this.af.database
    .list('/articles/', {
      query: {
        orderByChild: 'title',
        equalTo: term,
        limitToFirst: 10
      }
    }) as Observable<Article[]>;
}
```

If `Article` is a class, you should use the `map` operator to create actual `Article` instances (using a suitable constructor):

```ts
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Article } from '../models/index';

search(term: string): Observable<Article[]> {
  return this.af.database
    .list('/articles/', {
      query: {
        orderByChild: 'title',
        equalTo: term,
        limitToFirst: 10
      }
    })
    .map(list => list.map(item => new Article(item));
}
```